# Makefile の .suffix ルールが認識されない

Tags: makefile

AWS Lambda のデプロイをするときに
PHP のライブラリリスト (composer.json) を更新したときだけ
composer install をし直してからデプロイするみたいな Makefile を以下のように書いてみたんですが

```
deploy: src/composer.lock
    sam deploy ...
.json.lock:
    cd $(*D); composer install
```

```sh
# make deploy
make: *** No rule to make target `src/composer.lock', needed by `deploy'.  Stop.
```

というエラーになってしまいます

.c.o っていうサンプルをよく見かけるんですが .json.lock という書き方で
src/composer.json から src/composer.lock を生成するルールというのはできないのでしょうか

Comment: `.c.o` に関しては「暗黙のルール」として既に宣言されているものです。独自の拡張子を使用する場合は `.SUFFIXES` を指定します。`.SUFFIXES: .json .lock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` が最初から知っているビルトインルールに `.json.lock` はなさそうなので `.SUFFIXES:` を明示する必要がありそうです。

```
.SUFFIXES: .json .lock
.json.lock:
     なんちゃら
deploy: src/composer.lock
```

であるなら `deploy` を作るのには `src/composer.lock` が必要 `.SUFFIXES:` によって `src/composer.json` から `src/composer.lock` が作れると判断され `なんちゃら` の部分が実行されます。
# 入力する都合で `なんちゃら` 行の最初は `TAB` になっていませんからコピペ禁止で。

Comment: 動きました！　.SUFFIXESが必要なのですね

Answer (score 1):

追加で認識させるサフィックスを指定する必要があると思います。
Makefileに以下の記述を追加してみてください。

```
.SUFFIXES: .json .lock
```